# zone alarm 10 blocks eclipse updates

Tags: eclipse, alarm, updates

I have win 7 64 bit with zone alarm 10.  Although zone alarm says it gives permissions to access the internet, eclipse fails to reach the internet.  If I shut down zone alarm, eclipse can update fine - pretty conclusive.  How do I configure zone alarm to allow eclipse to update?

Comment: This is still a problem with Indigo and ZoneAlarm 10.1

I've looked at the "program control" -- Java, Eclipse, and other obvious programs work.  For contrast curl works fine under firewall protection.  

My expectation is that the problem like within Java7 because the updates work with Java6 and ZoneAlarm.  The tip from the Android user might work if you use the Android SDK but not for Eclipse.

Comment: Great point.  I have asked a moderator to re-title the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the two-step answer:
In ZoneAlarm go to firewall settings and set Public Zone security to Medium
and add the application 'SDK Manager.exe' to the Application Control Settings and allow inbound and outbound internet access.

The 'SDK Manager.exe' application is in the Android SDK folder that you installed to.